# Google Sheets importxml xpath to parse marcxml

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, xml-parsing, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to parse XML (MarcXML) in Google Sheets.

For example I try to get the value in the subfield with code="a" in the datafield with tag="245"

MarcXML example I'm trying to parse:
https://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/Sandburg/sandburg.xml

Google Sheets formula I tried:

```
=importxml(A1;"//datafield[@tag='245']/subfield[@code='a']")
```

However with the above formula I get the dreaded error `Imported content is empty.`

When I use this:

```
=importxml(A1;"/*")
```

it does output something (all the values together...)

Since Google Sheet's importxml is outputting something with xpath "/*" I think what I try to do should in theory work? Could someone make a suggestion?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the exact problem with your xpath query, but I guess it might be due to the differences of XML and MarcXML.

Anyway this xpath works fine based on the structure of your sample data:

```
=importxml(A1,"//*[@tag=245]/*[@code='a']")
```

It searches for *any* node that has a `tag` attribute with the value of `245`; and then looks for *any* child node that has a `code` attribute with the value of `'a'`.